Website Magazine backlinks
How bad is it for a website to have 42 backlinks from a online tourism website/magazine?
I've seen a number of these type websites for tourism all over the place. They provide good content for people visiting the area covered.
I assume Google is aware of these sites. However, reading StackExchange, it looks like Google doesn't like advertorial type links - which since they write a magazine is what I'm assuming this site is considered.
I think it's clear to readers that there are ads (and thus a paid relationship) but I don't know what the Google standards are.
I've just looked at the search console and it there are 42 now backlinks. (Maybe because of ads on multiple pages or because the post on their site is listed under several categories? I don't know.)
Should the company be asked to make all but one of those links no-follow? Or something else?
